# Difference in binding of functions calls?

Tags: javascript, binding, prototype

I have an object "me" with functions defined for it.

```
me.prototype.f = function(args){
    console.log("f called");
};
```

I need to provide f as a callback in an async function.

```
me.prototype.operation = function (){
    var self = this;
    var client; // an io client
    //client.on("data", self.f);                --a
    //client.on("data", self.f.bind(self))      --b
}
```

Is there any difference between a & b above in this case and is there any situation where a) might fail?

In which scenarios do we get a problem without binding? Generally it is when values might change based on the context. (eg. closure using loop index value)
So, what can be the different scenarios where values might act differently.

---

From the answer I arrived at the following conclusions. Please confirm the same :

a) The scope will change as the function is passed as reference and will pick up the local reference unless the context is not bound using bind, call or apply.

b) Specially in callbacks/async functions, if the context is changed (eg. setTimeout, the context will change, hence the meaning of self will change during call.)

c) It has no relation to closure, since in closure the Lexical Environment is checked for evaluating values, however, here the context during the time of execution is evaluated

Comment: You will get problems if you use `this` in your `f` function. Thats why you `bind` `this` to function.

Comment: Simple example `var a = {f: function(){console.log(this)}}; a.f(); var f = a.f; f();`. you lost your `this` in second execution same as you lost it with `self.f`

Comment: @Maxx If I call the function as `client.on("data", self.f);` , in that case also my `this` will be preserved since, context of self will be associated with the function call (as it is a member function). Then is there any difference in a) and b)

Comment: your `self` var is absolutly useless in your example, it's do nothing. in a) you pass to client some function `f`, in moment when your `client` calls `f`, `f` doesnt know anything about its context. in b) you bind your context to `f`

Comment: `self` here is referring to the instance of `me` and hence providing the functions associated with it. The two cases are commented which I want to discuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.f` is a reference to the `f` function.

`self.f.bind(self)` is a new function which when called invokes `f` with `self` as `this`.

> Is there any difference between a & b above in this case and is there
>   any situation where a) might fail?

Yes. The behaviour depends on how you make the call:

```js
function me() {}
me.prototype.f = function() {
  console.log(this);
};
me.prototype.operation = function() {
  client.on("this.f", this.f);
  client.on("this.f.bind(this)", this.f.bind(this));
};

var client = {
  on: function(whatever, callback) {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("=== " + whatever + " ===");
      self.f = callback;

      // `this` not specified
      //  `this.f` logs the global object, or `undefined` in strict mode
      //  `this.f.bind(this)` logs `me` instance
      callback();

      // `this` belongs to current function (passed to setTimeout)
      //  `this.f` logs the global object, or `undefined` in strict mode
      //  `this.f.bind(this)` logs `me` instance
      callback.call(this);

      // `self` is a reference to the client object
      //  `this.f` logs `client`
      //  `this.f.bind(this)` logs `me` instance
      callback.call(self);

      // `this` is determined by the calling object (client again)
      //  `this.f` logs `client`
      //  `this.f.bind(this)` logs `me` instance
      self.f();

    }, 1000);
  }
};


(new me()).operation();
```

## Update

I've decided to add more to the answer, as you've added more to the question. I am sorry that it turned out this long.

### How `this`works

*The value of `this` is determined on function call, not on function definition.*

- When calling a function which is not a property of an object `this`
  will be `undefined` in strict, or refer to the global object in
  non-strict mode.

  ```
  function f1() {
    console.log(this === window);
  }
  function f2() {
    'use strict';
    console.log(this === undefined);
  }

  f1();  // true
  f2();  // true
  ```
- When calling a function which is a property of an object, `this`
  will refer to the that object.

  ```
  var object = {
    f: function() {
      console.log(this === object);
    }
  };
  object.f();   // true
  ```
- When calling a function with the `new` prefix, `this` will refer to
  the newly created object.

  ```
  var backup;
  function Example() {
    backup = this;
    this.value = 0;
  }

  var example = new Example();
  console.log(example === backup);  // true
  console.log(example.value);       // 0
  ```
- When calling a function which is a not a property of an object, but
  is a part of the object's prototype chain, `this` will refer to the
  calling object.

  ```
  function Example() {}
  Example.prototype.f = function() {
    console.log(this === example);
  };

  var example = new Example();
  example.f();   // true
  ```

### Changing `this`

Mentioned behaviour is often not what we want. Consider the following situation.

```js
    function Counter() {
      this.count;
      this.limit;
      this.interval;
    }
    Counter.prototype.countTo = function(number) {
      this.count = 1;
      this.limit = number;
      this.interval = setInterval(update, 1000);

      function update() {
        console.log(this.count);
        if (++this.count > this.limit)
          clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    };

    var counter = new Counter();
    counter.countTo(5);   // undefined, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN...
```

`this` gets its value once the function is called, not when it's defined. The interval function will be called at a later time, and `this` will refer to the global object. In most cases, that is not what one's after.

#### Changing `this` implicitly

The historical way to solve the `setInterval` issue is to assign a reference of `this` to a variable visible by the problematic function, and use that variable instead.

```js
function Counter() {}
Counter.prototype.countTo = function(number) {
  this.count = 1;
  this.limit = number;

  var self = this;

  function update() {
    console.log(self.count);
    if (++self.count > self.limit)
      clearInterval(self.interval);
  }
  this.interval = setInterval(update, 1000);
};

var counter = new Counter();
counter.countTo(5);
```

The same using a closure, to prevent pollution of function scope.

```js
function Counter() {}

Counter.prototype.countTo = function(number) {
  this.count = 1;
  this.limit = number;

  this.interval = setInterval((function(self) {
    return function() {
      console.log(self.count);
      if (++self.count > self.limit)
        clearInterval(self.interval);
    };
  }(this)), 1000);
};

var counter = new Counter();
counter.countTo(5);
```

---

Creating a new `update` function whenever a `Counter` is created is not the most efficient way to do it. Let's say we want to move it to the prototype.

```js
function Counter() {
  this.count;
  this.limit;
  this.interval;
}
Counter.prototype.countTo = function(number) {
  this.count = 1;
  this.limit = number;
  this.interval = setInterval(this.update, 1000);
};
Counter.prototype.update = function() {
  console.log(this.count);
  if (++this.count > this.limit)
    clearInterval(this.interval);
};

var counter = new Counter();
counter.countTo(5); // undefined, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN...
```

The problem now is getting `update` to know about `self`s, since they are no longer defined in the same scope, and there's only one `update` function for all `Counter`s.

We can create a mediator function that will enclose the value (copy a reference) of `this` and use it to make the call.

```js
function Counter() {
  this.count;
  this.limit;
  this.interval;
}
Counter.prototype.countTo = function(number) {
  this.count = 1;
  this.limit = number;

  var update = (function(self) {
    return function() {
      self.update();
    };
  }(this));

  this.interval = setInterval(update, 1000);
};
Counter.prototype.update = function() {
  console.log(this.count);
  if (++this.count > this.limit)
    clearInterval(this.interval);
};

var counter = new Counter();
counter.countTo(5);
```

We can use arrow functions, which bind `this` lexically, that is, its value is determined on function definition, regardless of how or when it's called.

```js
function Counter() {
  this.count;
  this.limit;
  this.interval;
}
Counter.prototype.countTo = function(number) {
  this.count = 1;
  this.limit = number;
  this.interval = setInterval(() => this.update(), 1000); // neat.
};
Counter.prototype.update = function() {
  console.log(this.count);
  if (++this.count > this.limit)
    clearInterval(this.interval);
};

var counter = new Counter();
counter.countTo(5);
```

#### Changing `this` explicitly

Let's say our `update` function is defined elsewhere, and we wish to use it instead of our prototype function.

```js
function Counter(to) {
  this.count;
  this.limit;
  this.interval;
}
Counter.prototype.countTo = function(number) {
  this.count = 1;
  this.limit = number;
  this.interval = setInterval(update, 1000);
};

function update() {
  console.log(this.count);
  if (++this.count > this.limit)
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}

var counter = new Counter();
counter.countTo(5); // undefined, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN...
```

Using the previously mentioned approaches, we could attach a reference to `update` within the object or its prototype, and use, say, an arrow function to bind `this`. If we don't like that sort of overhead, we have three powerful functions at our disposal for explicitly setting `this`:

Calling `bind` on a function results in a new function whose `this` is set to the first parameter.

```js
function Counter(to) {
  this.count;
  this.limit;
  this.interval;
}
Counter.prototype.countTo = function(number) {
  this.count = 1;
  this.limit = number;
  this.interval = setInterval(update.bind(this), 1000); // not bad.
};

function update() {
  console.log(this.count);
  if (++this.count > this.limit)
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
var counter = new Counter();
counter.countTo(5);
```

Using `call` or `apply` on a function will make the call with `this` set to the first parameter.

```js
function Counter(to) {
  this.count;
  this.limit;
  this.interval;
}
Counter.prototype.countTo = function(number) {
  this.count = 1;
  this.limit = number;
  var self = this;
  this.interval = setInterval(function() {
    update.call(self);
  }, 1000);
};

function update() {
  console.log(this.count);
  if (++this.count > this.limit)
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}

var counter = new Counter();
counter.countTo(5);
```

Comment: Thanks, I experimented a lot with the above. Came up will following observations. 
a) The scope will change as the function is passed as reference and will pick up the local reference unless the context is not bound using bind, call or apply.
b) Specially in callbacks/async functions, if the context is changed (eg. setTimeout, the context will change, hence the meaning of self will change during call.)
c) It has no relation to closure, since in closure the Lexical Environment is checked for evaluating values, however, here the context during the time of execution is evaluated

Comment: Your observations are correct. The point is that `this` is determined on _function call_, not on _function definition_.

Comment: In many situations this is not what you want, and in order to circumvent it, you explicitly set the `this` value using `bind`, `call` or `apply`, or a simple function using the stored reference of `this` from its environment.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention are ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) which bind `this` lexically, that is, it is determined on _function definition_.

Comment: The last two points are interesting. In  `simple function using the stored reference of this` - do you mean by calling the function with the stored reference as one of the parameters.

Comment: I added some stuff to the answer in hope it answers your questions.